# How to access HTTPS on EC2 site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I've done the following:

1. Requested HTTPS certificate via AWS Certificate Manager for mydomain.com
2. Validated HTTPS certificate
3. Edited security groups from my instance to allow for the following:
   [image]
4. I have a load balancer that listens at port 80 for HTTP to my app's port. This works.
   Now, I added a listener for HTTPS with the certificate from Step 1
   [image]
5. Restarted my app. Waited 6 hours as well, no change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your instance port will remain same for both HTTP & HTTPS i.e 7777 in your case.

> You have mis-configured your instance port for HTTPS to 80, make it to
> point 7777.